# Editorial Design: Margin around side note embedded in main body of text (Adobe InDesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, text, typesetting, editorial-design

I am working on a layout draft in Adobe InDesign which includes some side notes. These I am trying to "embed" into the main text by putting them/their `text frame` on the far right side of the page where they intersect with the main text's frame.

How can I ad proper a (white) margin along the top, bottom and left side of the side note's `text frame`? Currently my draft looks like this:

[image: Layout-Draft]

[image: Layout-Draft_NoGuides]

Comment: @ZachSaucier My apologies for not including this info in the first place: I am using Adobe InDesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply enter the offset values in the Text Wrap panel:

> [image]

You can read more in the help docs:

- [**Learn how to wrap text around objects in InDesign - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-wrap.html)

If you would rather *inset* the text, you can open the text frame options (*Object → Text Frame Options...* or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and set "Inset Spacing":

> [image]

Comment: You can also adjust the inset spacing of the text box with the ⌘+b shortcut to help obtain the desired effect.